# Beautiful soup: Extract everything between two tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract data from HTML files. I want to get all of the information between two tags. This means that if I have an HTML section like this:

```
<h1></h1>
Text <i>here</i> has no tag
<div>This is in a div</div>
<h1></h1>
```

Then if I wanted all of the information between the first h1 and the second h1, the output would look like this:

```
Text <i>here</i> has no tag
<div>This is in a div</div>
```

I've tried nextsibling loops, but there always seems to be a catch. Is there a command in beautifulsoup that simply pulls everything (Text, newlines, divs, special characters) that is between element "A" and element "B"?

Comment: Needs more snippets! seriously though, when you ask a question, you need to post code so that we can offer guidance.

Comment: You're right. I'm on a cellphone with no internet access on my computer. Im in Oregon near the fires so everything is bad. I was just wondering if there was a command in beautifulsoup for this, or if I should stick to bashing pcregrep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to `.extract()` all content in front of first `<h1>` and after second `<h1>` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''
This I <b>don't</b> want
<h1></h1>
Text <i>here</i> has no tag
<div>This is in a div</div>
<h1></h1>
This I <b>don't</b> want too
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for c in list(soup.contents):
    if c is soup.h1 or c.find_previous('h1') is soup.h1:
        continue
    c.extract()

for h1 in soup.select('h1'):
    h1.extract()

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
Text <i>here</i> has no tag
<div>This is in a div</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how, you can simply target their parent or you can wrap them in the container
and extract all children of that parent you're targeting like the following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = """
<div class="container">
    <h1></h1>
        Text <i>here</i> has no tag
        <div>This is in a div</div>
    <h1></h1>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find('div').findChildren()
print(results)
```

or

```
print(soup.find('h1').findAllNext())
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. As great as Beautifulsoup sounds, I think I feel more comfortable using bash scripting right now.

Comment: glad to help @MrNo