# Beautiful soup: Extract everything between two tags when these tags have different ids

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

[Beautiful soup: Extract everything between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63903668/beautiful-soup-extract-everything-between-two-tags)

I have seen a question through the above link where we are getting the information between two tags. Whereas I need to get the information between the tags when these tags are having two different id attribute values.

```
    <h1 id = 'beautiful' ></h1>
    Text <i>here</i> has no tag
    <div>This is in a div</div>
    <h1 id = 'good' ></h1>
```

---

---

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract data from HTML files. I want to get all of the information between the two tags. This means that if I have an HTML section like this:

```
    <h1></h1>
    Text <i>here</i> has no tag
    <div>This is in a div</div>
    <h1></h1>
```

Then if I wanted all of the information between the first h1 and the second h1, the output would look like this:

```
    Text <i>here</i> has no tag
    <div>This is in a div</div>
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''
This I <b>don't</b> want
<h1></h1>
Text <i>here</i> has no tag
<div>This is in a div</div>
<h1></h1>
This I <b>don't</b> want too
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for c in list(soup.contents):
    if c is soup.h1 or c.find_previous('h1') is soup.h1:
        continue
    c.extract()

for h1 in soup.select('h1'):
    h1.extract()

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
Text <i>here</i> has no tag
<div>This is in a div</div>
```

This is working without ids.

Could someone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

The *parent* & *decompose* methods might be helpful for you.

```
# 1. Find the first item you are looking for. 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
hElem = soup.find("h1", {'id': 'beautiful'})


# 2. Find the second condition. 

endElem = soup.find('h1', {'id': 'good'})


# 3. Get parent element that contains both. 

hParent = hElem.parent  # Can be made more complex if multiple ancestors are needed to contain both conditions.


# 4. Iterate through children and remove all children outside the conditions.

childrenElems = hParent.children
inBetween = true
for child in childrenElems:
  if not inBetween:  
    child.decompose()
  if child == endElem:
    inBetween = false 

#  Remaining data.
print(childrenElems)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate through the soup contents yourself and build a block of elements seen between each `<h1>` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag


html = """
<h1 id = '1' ></h1>
Text1 <i>here</i> has no tag
<div>This is in a div</div>
<h1 id = '2' ></h1>
Text2 <i>here</i> has no tag
<div>This is in a div</div>
<h1 id = '3' ></h1>
Text3 <i>here</i> has no tag
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

block = []
blocks = []
h1 = False

for el in soup.contents:
    if type(el) == Tag and el.name == 'h1':
        # Has a h1 tag been seen yet?
        if h1:
            blocks.append(block)
            block = []
        h1 = True
    elif h1:
        block.append(el)

# Add any final elements (missing a next h1)
if block:
    blocks.append(block)
        
# Display each block as html soup
for b in blocks:        
    soup.contents = b
    print(soup)        
    print("--------------")
```

This example would have 3 such blocks of elements:

```
Text1 <i>here</i> has no tag
<div>This is in a div</div>

--------------

Text2 <i>here</i> has no tag
<div>This is in a div</div>

--------------

Text3 <i>here</i> has no tag

--------------
```